# Is there a way to merge .less with .css in Gulp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, gulp

so far I didn't find a solution. Here's what I came up with for now :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uncss = require('gulp-uncss');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-minify-css'); 
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var stripCssComments = require('gulp-strip-css-comments');

gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/*.css')
      .pipe(stripCssComments({all:true}))
      .pipe(concat('plugins.css'))
      .pipe(uncss({html: ['index.html']}))
      .pipe(minifyCSS())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});
gulp.task('less', function() {
    return gulp.src('css/*.less')
      .pipe(less())
      .pipe(stripCssComments({all:true}))
      .pipe(concat('styles.css'))
      .pipe(uncss({html: ['index.html']}))
      .pipe(minifyCSS())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});
```

basically I'm trying to merge the .less with the .css, I only want one .css in build. I tried different syntaxes to achieve this effect but to no avail, gulp always send me an error message. Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `.css` files are in `css/` as your `css` task says, why not just rename them `.less`?

If you don't want to do that, [less offers the ability](http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options) (unlike Sass) to import raw CSS files.

```
@import (css) "file1.css";
@import (css) "files2.css";
...
```

From your tasks, I don't see why you couldn't merge the 2 into a single `'less'` task, and update your main `.less` file to import all `.css` files up front.

Comment: hm yeah thats a way to look at the problem I didnt think about.. I basically renamed all my bootstrap, jquery ui stuff to .less and then its ok. thanks

Comment: Almost two years later I can confirm this is still the case - although if you're trying to source map with gulp-sourcemaps you may run into issues.

Comment: As it turns out it is not sourcemaps that are the issue but using both gulp-sourcemaps and gulp-clean-css which causes issues because it looks like clean-css tries to clean the map files.

Answer (score 4):

I have been working on this and believe I have a clean solution using several gulp plugins.

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
  var cssFiles = [src + 'styles/*.css', 'bower_components/jquery.onoff/dist/jquery.onoff.css'];
  var cssStream = gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles().concat(cssFiles))
        .pipe(plugins.filter('*.css'))
        .pipe(order([
      "app/styles/site.css",
      "*"
    ]));

  var lessStream =  gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(plugins.filter('*.less'))
    .pipe(less({
      paths: [ path.join(__dirname, 'less', 'includes') ]
    }));

  return merge(cssStream, lessStream)
        .pipe(plugins.concat('main.css'))
        .pipe(minifyCSS({keepBreaks:true}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'css'));
});
```

My example is showing auto inclusion of bower files where they are set up correctly and adding them into the cssFiles variable were they are not.  This css stream is merged with the less stream that runs in a similar way.  I would imagine that adding SASS files in the same way would be simple.  My package.json contains more than is necessary for this implementation but looks like this.

```
{
  "name": "MHD_Site_v3",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "bower": "~0.8.0",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-logger": "0.0.2"
    "gulp": "^3.8.11",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.2.4",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.3",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-jade": "^0.11.0",
    "gulp-less": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.8.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^0.1.8",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
    "less-plugin-clean-css": "^1.4.0",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.5.0",
    "merge-stream": "^0.1.7",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.5",
    "path": "^0.11.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```